# Gulp task 'inject:vendor' does not inject Bower dependencies

Tags: gulp, jhipster, gulp-inject

After upgrading to the latest version `3.4.1` of JHipster, I noticed that `gulp inject` does not inject my custom Bower dependencies into `index.html`. So I tried to delete all the prepackaged script tags and get them injected again.

Surprisingly, it did not work. Nothing gets injected.

I don't see no tickets, no discussions mentioning this problem. Is this just my environment? Can someone verify that this is an issue?

**How to reproduce:**

- take [JHipster sample app](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app) (latest version is `3.4.1` at the time of writing)
- delete prepackaged bower references from `index.html`

  ```
  <!-- build:js app/vendor.js -->
  <!-- bower:js -->
  ... all lines are deleted here ...
  <!-- endinject -->
  <!-- endbuild -->
  ```
- run `gulp inject`
- nothing is injected into the `bower:js` section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can verify that `gulp inject` does not inject the bower dependencies, but both `gulp inject:dep` and `gulp inject:vendor` worked correctly for me.  Not sure why that is.

I would recommend calling just `gulp` which will start watching your files and inject any dependencies for you.

Comment: Right, `gulp inject:dep` being called separately works, but not when it's combined with other sub-tasks. Probably, it has something to do with multiple sub-tasks writing to the same `index.html` file. Anyway, your suggestion works. Thanks.